# Can Tablesorter ajax filter my JSON-populated table?

Tags: ajax, json, server-side, tablesorter

I have a table that I want to page/sort with Tablesorter, and I have passed the data to the table with JSON. I would like it to add/delete/update rows as rows are added etc. in the JSON. However, the filtering also happens serverside, which means a several-second lag every time you change pages or want to search, as the request is made to a PHP page. When you have potentially several thousand rows it can get tedious.

Is it at all possible to get Tablesorter to load all rows first, and page and filter those rows via AJAX, in the same way as it does by default (ie without sending requests back and forth)? And yet still update the JSON as it changes? Or will I have to do all requests server-side as the data is being fetched dynamically? Is there any way to speed up the calls, alternatively?

Comment: You could just make the php page populate the entire table (hide the tbody so the page loads faster) then initialize tablesorter without using any ajax parameters.